# getting Typeerror : unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DeferredAttribute' and 'int' instead of value

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to count the number of reviews I've got for a movie. Here I'm increasing number_rating by 1 value every time you add a new review by new user.

here is my views.py code.

```
class ReviewCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
serializer_class = ReviewSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    return Review.objects.all()

    # ************
def perform_create(self, serializer):    # provides overring | Save and deletion hooks | concrete class views
    pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')           # also have perform_update perform_destroy
    watchlist_movie = watchlist.objects.get(pk=pk)

    review_user = self.request.user        # we are getting current user / ERROR
    review_queryset = Review.objects.filter(watchlist=watchlist_movie, review_user=review_user)

    if review_queryset.exists():        # ERROR
        raise ValidationError('You have already reviewed this movie.')
    
    if watchlist.number_ratings == 0:
                                # here providing validated data from serializers
        watchlist.avg_rating = serializer.validated_data['rating']
    else:
                                # (old rating + new rating) / 2
        watchlist.avg_rating = (watchlist.avg_rating + serializer.validated_data['rating']) / 2

    # for number of ratings == current ratings + one.
    watchlist.number_ratings = watchlist.number_ratings + 1
    watchlist.save()

    serializer.save(watchlist = watchlist_movie, review_user = review_user)
```

error is coming to the else part, adding + 1 to existing count to show the actual number count.

What's this error about, How to solve this kind-of errors in future?

Comment: Typos: `watchlist.*` → `watchlist_movie.*`

Comment: How is it not working yet you accepted the answer (with another typo)?